# Why didn't the guns pop up in Incredibles 2?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-incredibles, incredibles-2

In the *The Incredibles*, when EDNA takes in Elastigirl to show the suits details, the guns pop up.

But in *Incredibles 2*, when she takes in Bob and Jack-Jack, the guns do not show up.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

## No more demonstration is needed.

The suit is bulletproof, as a default, there is no need to prove it over again.

Edna..in *The Incredibles*

> Edna: Shh! Darling! Shh! I cut it a little roomy for the free 
>   movement. The fabric is comfortable for sensitive skin, and can also withstand 
>   a temperature of over 1000 degrees. **Completely bulletproof**. And machine 
>   washable, darling. That's a new feature.
>
> HELEN
>
> What on earth do you think the baby will be doing?!
>
> Edna
>
> Well, I'm sure I don't know, darling. Luck favors the 
>   prepared. **I didn't know the baby's powers, so I covered the basics**.

---

It occurs to me that you *might* be referring to these guns...

[image]

However, we don't see the entire clip (I'm dubious about the legality of the youtube clip, but that's another matter)...but it seems likely that since the reason for the visit is to authorise Jack-Jack to the testing area the guns aren't necessary....assuming they deployed in the first place (since we don't see them). Edna's already approved him and the machines are just recording the details.

Plus, of course, he's already wearing his bulletproof onesie!